# Hide/show a custom block

Tags: 8, blocks

I have created a custom block of id `downloadourapp` and I would like to show/hide it base on certain statements.

I have create my custom module along with `.module` file where the code should be, however, I failed to find the right function to be used for that matter.

is `hook_block_view_alter` is the right function and how to hide or show this `downloadourapp` specific block.

Comment: @NoSssweat  the question does answer my question but for some reason it is not working for me, can you please check the updated section of my question ?

Comment: Needs to be `return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCa....`

Comment: Also, you'll probably need to add a [cache context](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays#conceptual-example) of user agent, otherwise, it's probably going to cache the result of whatever the user agent happens to be on the first visit.

Comment: @NoSssweat `return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheableDependency($block);` worked for me but the problem lies under `if ($block->getPluginId() == 'downloadourapp') {` because when I remove this line, `downloadourapp` block is hidden for good along with all other blocks.
**Note:** I am sure the block id is `downloadourapp` as taken from the block edit url `/admin/structure/block/manage/downloadourapp` but why it not being respected in code ?

Comment: Plugin ID doesn't equal Block ID, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okEmm.png). You can find the Plugin ID with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) or alternatively change it to `if ($block->id() = 'downloadourapp') {`

Comment: `$block->id()` was the missed part in my code, please add the entire code as an answer so I can accept it, thank you

Comment: Questions cannot be changed when they get an answer. They aren't though as back-and-forth with the users who answer. The questions cannot be edited basing on what a user answered, and you cannot expect users change their answers basing on how you changed the question because an answer the question got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin ID doesn't equal Block ID, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okEmm.png).

[isForbidden](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21AccessResultInterface.php/function/AccessResultInterface%3A%3AisForbidden/8.2.x) is not a static function, need to use [forbidden](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21AccessResult.php/function/AccessResult%3A%3Aforbidden/8.2.x).

```
if ($block->id() == 'downloadourapp') {

    // If the user's phone is Android.
    if(preg_match("/(android)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {

    return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheableDependency($block);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `hook_block_view_alter()` is not the hook you are looking for.

Try using [`hook_block_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.4.x) to control access to the block instead.

If you created your custom block programmatically, you can even control visibility directly from inside the block class via [`blockAccess()`](https://www.webwash.net/programmatically-create-block-drupal-8/).